# 2D Unity: How to make a enemy jump from a navmesh platform to another?

Tags: unity, 2d, platformer, unityscript

I'm currently working on a 2d platformer, however I came across an issue where the enemy moves within a certain range of the platform.

[image: An example of my game so far, with navmesh shown]

In this case I use a navmesh to limit the enemy's movement however I want the enemies to be able to jump within platforms.

I'm not sure how to achieve this effect, where the enemy moves in the platform a couple of times and the jumps into the next one until the player gets in range for it to attack the player.

How can I acheive this effect? Should i keep on using navmeshes or try another way around?

Comment: Unity's built-in navmesh is built for navigating 2D floor areas (like in a top-down game or full 3D environment). [For a side-on platformer you'll need a custom solution](http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/YoannPignole/20150427/241995/The_Hobbyist_Coder_3__2D_platformers_pathfinding__part_12.php).

Comment: are you using the free version of Unity, or Unity Pro? I'm pretty sure the built in navmesh also only supports the feature your asking about in the Pro version. That is, having AI "jump" between navmesh.

Comment: Unity Pro and Unity Standard are the same now -- Only difference is that Unity Pro provides the dark theme for the editor, and the ability to remove the Unity Splash screen.